# Identifying faulting address on General Protection Fault (x86)

Tags: operating-system, x86, osdev, interrupt-handling

I am trying to write a ISR for the General Protection Fault (GP#13) on x86. I am unable to figure out from the INTEL docs as to how I can find out the faulting address causing the exception. I know that for Page fault exceptions (GP#14) the cr2 register holds the faulting address. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All references I make here are from [AMD64 Architecture Programmer's Manual Volume 2: System Programming](http://support.amd.com/us/Processor_TechDocs/24593_APM_v2.pdf), which also describes the legacy protected-mode (i.e., x86) behavior.

Figure 8-8 on page 240 shows the stack layout after an interrupt to the same privilege level (that is, the stack layout when an ISR is entered):

[image: Stack After Interrupt to Same Privilege Level]

In Section 8.2.14, you can see that `#GP` provides an error code and the following is also of interest:

> **Program Restart.** `#GP` is a fault-type exception. In most cases, the
>   saved instruction pointer points to the instruction that caused the
>   `#GP`. See “Exceptions During a Task Switch” on page 230 for a description of the consequences when this exception occurs during a
>   task switch.

The referenced section mentions the following:

> An exception can occur during a task switch while loading a segment
>   selector. Page faults can also occur when accessing a TSS. In these
>   cases, the hardware task-switch mechanism completes loading the new
>   task state from the TSS, and then triggers the appropriate exception
>   mechanism. No other checks are performed. **When this happens, the saved
>   instruction pointer points to the first instruction in the new task.**

So, unless you are using hardware task switching, the saved instruction pointer always point to the faulting instruction.

To get the address of the faulting instruction, simple get the saved `EIP` and `CS` values from the stack in your ISR. (If you're using a flat memory model and all your segments cover the whole 4GB, the saved `CS` is of no interest, of course).

```
movl 4(%esp), %eax
movw 8(%esp), %ebx
```

Now, `EAX`contains the saved `EIP` and `EBX` the saved `CS`.

**Edit:** Of course, as pointed out by [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/968261/alex) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360888/identifying-faulting-address-on-general-protection-fault-x86/#comment13352050_10361732), in case the `#GP` was caused by a memory access and you want the address of the accessed memory, you will need to decode the faulting instruction.

Comment: And to get the actual address (if #GP was caused by a memory access), the OP will need to decode the instruction at CS:EIP and likely use register values to substitute into various ECX*4+EAX+3.